# Bootstrap spinner-border disappear

Tags: javascript, php, html

currently I try to make website which should print some line after I click a link. 
So far so good, now I want to add a spinner-border from bootstrap. It works pretty well but I have no idea how to remove it again.

```
              <p>New here? Sign up <a href="?signup">here</a>.</p><br>
          <?php
          if(isset($_GET['signup'])) {
            echo '<div class="spinner-border" role="status"></div>';
            for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
                flush();
                ob_flush();
                sleep(1);
            }
            echo "<span><h1>Sign up</h1>";
```

Answer (score 0):

So I *think* what you're trying to do isn't really something you'd want to use PHP for.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like what you want is:

1. Show a page with a link to a sign up form
2. When you click the link, show a spinner
3. Hide the spinner after a second, and show the Sign up page

PHP can't be used to create a dynamic page like this, as it executes all of the code on the server, before sending it to your browser.

Really, if what you want is a link to a sign up page, all you need is a separate file instead, as then you can link to that and when you click it, the new page content would be there.

However, if you want to use the spinner, things will get more complicated as you would need to use some ajax to load the page content.

Alternatively, if all you want is a spinner to show before showing the content, you could let the page reload as normal, showing the spinner. Then hide the spinner using JavaScript.

If you had your `spinner-border` class, you could do something like

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('spinner-border').style.display = 'none';
```